# How to get contents of CKEDITOR when postingback in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ckeditor

I used CKEDITOR in my ASP.NET project, the page contains `asp:TextBox` with `TextMode="Multiline"` and a linkbutton.
When I press linkbutton I can't get the TextBox value in postback..
No errors occured...
How to get content in server side? I was thinking of use jQuery to track changes on content of CK and copy it to the hidden textarea..but didn't seem to be right.

I'm using javascript version of **CK v4.2**, not .net library version.

**Addition:**
In the sample downloaded with CKEditor.zip file you can see that getting text in server side is easy using $_POST.
Why in ASP.NET isn't?

**Update:**
This issue occurs when using RadScriptManager, RadAjaxManager and RadAjaxPanel (from telerik).

Answer (score 2):

On the ASPX Page set the CKEditor control as:

```
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" runat="server"/>
```

On the code behind page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        string text1 = CKEditor1.Text;
        string text2 = CKEditor1.Value;
        ...
    }
}
```

Remember to add/include proper references to CKEditor binaries

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. On a simple page I tested a LinkButton and a Button. The problem is that a LinkButton does not submit the form directly. It renders as a link and calls __doPostBack event so this is a problem for CKEditor. I tried to set the textarea like [Nirmal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18379757/259881) suggested but that didn't work too. Here is how I solved it.

Header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { $("#tBody").ckeditor(); });

    function setValue() {
        $("#hfBody").val(CKEDITOR.instances.tBody.getData());
    }
</script>
```

Inside the form:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tBody" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"/>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfBody" runat="server" />
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnSend" Text="Link" runat="server" OnClick="X_Click"
OnClientClick="setValue()"/>
```

C#

```
protected void X_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    divResult.InnerHtml = hfBody.Value;
    tBody.Text = hfBody.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this might help

```
string newText = ((CKedit.CKeditor)(e.Item.FindControl("txtBox"))).Value;
```

else use updatepanel to retain its value on postback

Comment: as I said "I'm using javascript version of CK v4.2, not .net library version." so there's no CKeditor class

Answer (score 0):

One of my co-workers solved it by setting `setup` property when init tinymce like this:

```
setup: function (ed) {
    ed.on('change', function (e) {
        ed.save();
    });
}
```

This will save content to editor when change event called.

Answer (score 0):

You have will get the data try below code :

var editorText = CKEDITOR.instances.txtinstruction.getData();
 _msemailsetup.BodyMessage = editorText ;

Answer (score 0):

```
HtmlTextArea rtf = item.FindControl("ckcontent") as HtmlTextArea;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -1):

before  firing postback  event call this function for set value

```
function setValue() 
{
     $("#txtinstruction").val(CKEDITOR.instances.txtinstruction.getData());
}
```

`txtinstruction` is id of textbox or textarea

Comment: If I didn't find another solution I'll use yours, I think there should be another way other than copying data from CK to a hidden control....

Comment: make ValidateRequest="false" in PAGE directive